# Free Svg to vector PDF converter

Tags: macos, vector-graphics, svg

I'm looking for a free interactive or CLI tool to convert SVG files to vector PDF running on a Mac.
The goal is to use the resulting files in Xcode image assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) should do nicely.

`inkscape input.svg --export-pdf=output.pdf`

Alternatives may be `convert` from [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) (although I am not sure this preserves the figure as a vector graphic) or `rsvg-convert` from [librsvg](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/LibRsvg). (On how to install the latter on Mac, see [this Stackoverflow question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513244).)